# What kind of server needs select

Tags: linux, sockets, unix, server

I know that a server normally open one port and listen it.

Today I learnt that there was a function `select` in system Unix-Like. With `select` we can listen multi-sockets.

I just can't imagine a case where we need to use `select`. If we have two sockets, it means that we are listening two ports, right? So I have a question:
What kind of server would open more than one port but receive and process the same type of requests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `select` helps with handling reads and writes on multiple sockets. It doesn't have to be multiple *server* sockets. The most typical use is for multiplexing a large number of *client* sockets.

You have a server with one listening socket. Each time you `accept` a connection, you add the new client socket to the multiplexing pool. `select` then returns any time any of those sockets has data available to read. The big win is that you're doing all this with one thread.

Answer (score 0):

Ummm... remember the difference between *ports* and *sockets.*

A "port" is like a telephone-number.  But a single phone-number could be handling any number of "calls!"

A "socket," then, represents a single telephone-call:  a currently active connection between this server and a particular client.  Each connection, by definition, "takes place over a particular port," but any number of connections might exist at the same time.

(The "accept" operation corresponds to: picking up the phone.)

So, then, what `select()` buys you is the ability to *monitor* any number of sockets at one time.  It examines all the sockets, waits *(if necessary)* for something to happen on any one of them, and returns **one** message to you.  Now, the design of your server becomes "a simple loop."  No matter how many sockets you're listening to, and no matter how many of them have messages waiting, `select()` will return messages to you *one at a time.*

It's basically the case that "every server out there will use a `select()` loop at its heart, unless there's an exceptionally wonderful reason *not* to.

Answer (score 0):

You also get as socket for each connection that you've `accept`ed on the listening (server) socket.
`select`ing among these (client) sockets and the server `socket` (readable => new connection) allows you to write apps such as chat servers efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:

> One traditional way to write network servers is to have the main
>   server block on accept(), waiting for a connection. Once a connection
>   comes in, the server fork()s, the child process handles the connection
>   and the main server is able to service new incoming requests.
>
> With select(), instead of having a process for each request, there is
>   usually only one process that "multi-plexes" all requests, servicing
>   each request as much as it can.
>
> So one main advantage of using select() is that your server will only
>   require a single process to handle all requests. Thus, your server
>   will not need shared memory or synchronization primitives for
>   different 'tasks' to communicate.
>
> One major disadvantage of using select(), is that your server cannot
>   act like there's only one client, like with a fork()'ing solution. For
>   example, with a fork()'ing solution, after the server fork()s, the
>   child process works with the client as if there was only one client in
>   the universe -- the child does not have to worry about new incoming
>   connections or the existence of other sockets. With select(), the
>   programming isn't as transparent.

http://www.lowtek.com/sockets/select.html